# PHP cookies working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to setup cookies on a live webserver. This is the code that I'm using to set up the cookie:

```
$authenticator = hash('sha256', random_bytes(9));
$expiry = time() + (86400 * 1825);
setcookie('setfirst', $authenticator, $expiry, "/");
```

The cookie works perfectly on localhost and on infinityfree. But if I upload my site to hostgator the cookie doesn't get set at all. I tried adding a try/catch to see if it returns any errors but I didn't get anything.

Am I doing something wrong? or is it time to change hosting providers?

Comment: Are you using the same PHP version on localhost and webserver? `sha256` to `hash_algos` was added in PHP 7.1

Comment: @Adrian Kokot Nope that's not it unfortunately. The authenticator does generate a key and it does upload it to my database.

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned on? A common case for cookies not working is white space or a BOM at the beginning of a file, outside of `<?php`

Comment: You should also inspect the raw HTTP response to see if it includes cookie data, regardless of whether a browser does anything with it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yup I have error reporting on and it doesn't have any BOMs. I checked the HTTP response and also used a cookie manager to check for available cookies on my site. The weird thing is, it works on Infinityfree but not on Hostgator. I used the exact same files as well so I don't understand why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I don’t know anything about those specific hosts, but my last guess would be something in the server config. I’m guessing it is Apache, so maybe something is set to not let the cookies through, or maybe the handler for PHP is registered different, CGI, FPM, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I finally figured it out after hours of debugging! Apparently I have to set a cookie before adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Hope it helps anyone who faces this issue with hostgator!